# Twitter bootstrap - break-word not work on dropdown-menu

Tags: drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap, word-wrap

I applied `word-wrap: break-word` to twitter bootstrap dropdown-nemu, but it didn't work. Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ex5fA/).

I tried a simplified sample and it worked:

```
<ul style="width: 60px">
    <li>
        <a style="word-wrap: break-word">fdsssssssssssssssssssssssssdfdsfsdfsdf</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It was because of `white-space: nowrap` property with link.. add this line:

```
<li><a href="#" style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: normal;">sometextsometextsometextsometextsometext</a></li>
```

..or use full fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ex5fA/45/ (you had also typos with your `.dropdown-menu` selector.. it was typed `.dorpdown-nenu` ;)

Comment: I waste 3 hours to figure this, too late to see this but you save my life.