# break the dropdown text length to next line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want the length of my dropdown text to come to the next line after certain width.

I tried `white-space:normal;` but that isn't working.

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenu1" href="#">Dropdown trigger</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else heresssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/n7r4mjf2/) is the fiddle.

**UPDATE** : It's been fixed. Was missing `word-wrap: break-word;`

Thanks for quick responses everyone.

Comment: i think you have to add first a max width to your dropdown thing.

Comment: Use `word-wrap: break-word;`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Twitter bootstrap - break-word not work on dropdown-menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128465/twitter-bootstrap-break-word-not-work-on-dropdown-menu)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.dropdown-menu>li>a {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: normal;
}

.dropdown-menu{
    max-width: 200px;
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n7r4mjf2/3/)

Answer (score 3):

Use the following CSS:

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    width: 200px; /* change accordingly */
    white-space: normal;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n7r4mjf2/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Simple as that, just keep an eye on the longest word, otherwise they overflow the container

```
.dropdown-menu{
    max-width: 200px;
}

.dropdown-menu > li > a{
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do it :

```
.dropdown-menu>li>a {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-all;
    white-space: normal;
}
.dropdown-menu{
  //give some width
}
```

Answer (score 2):

just update your css with the below

**CSS**

```
.dropdown-menu {
    width: 200px;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
    word-break: break-all;
    white-space:normal;
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n7r4mjf2/6/)

Answer (score 2):

Use following css:

> ```
> .dropdown ul{width: 250px; word-wrap: break-word;} 
>
> .dropdown li a {white-space: normal !important;}
> ```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n7r4mjf2/7/)

Answer (score 1):

The reason `white-space-normal` or `word-break: break-word;` is not working for you is because by default `bootstrap` css library is applying following css property to the anchor tag.

```
dropdown-menu>li>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #333;
  white-space: nowrap;display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #333;
  white-space: nowrap; // this is the culprit
}
```

So the last line `white-space: nowrap;` is what is preventing the you from breaking the line, since thats taking priority.

**My Solution:**

- Overriding the `white-space` css property with specificity `!important`.
- Also adding `word-break: break-word;` property to the anchor tag, so that the text will be better formatted.

**Live Demo @ JSFiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/n7r4mjf2/8/**